# AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: entity-framework-6, automapper

Description: I have one Web application which uses Automapper 4.1.1.0 version with EF 6 for mapping.

This application throws error intermittently specially when more number of records are fetched and / or more number of concurrent users are operating on this application.

Error details:

```
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Product_8AFB94389ADEA7181732D39AAE7B3AAB16F6979897F600C1B5E2A8F50A0AFDFDError Token:637170760073663598
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: 

Mapping types:
Product -> ProductBO
Org.app.Entity.DataModel.Inventory.Product -> Org.app.BusinessObjects.Models.ProductBO

Destination path:
List`1[35]

Source value:
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Product_8AFB94389ADEA7181732D39AAE7B3AAB16F6979897F600C1B5E2A8F50A0AFDFD ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at AutoMapper.TypeMap.<get_AfterMap>b__40_0(Object src, Object dest)
   at AutoMapper.Mappers.TypeMapObjectMapperRegistry.PropertyMapMappingStrategy.Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper)
   at AutoMapper.Mappers.TypeMapMapper.Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper)
   at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

The search API calls

```
products.Result = Mapper.Map<List<ProductBO>>(ProductList.ToList())
```

It has a custom automapper configuration class

```
  public static class AutoMapperConfiguration
    {

        public static void Configure()

        {
                Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductBO>()
..
```

This is called from Startup.cs  `AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();`

Have anyone faced this issue with this version of Automapper ? Would be grateful if you  can provide any idea to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: You best bet is to upgrade AutoMapper.

Comment: Thanks @LucianBargaoanu,  however since this would require lot of effort to upgrade to latest version i was looking for some quick fix if possible.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not in your own code? Are you creating _all_ the needed maps before calling `Map`?

Comment: Yes the Configure function contains all the mappings with Mapper.CreateMap<ob1Entity, ob1BO>() is called at start up and it did not have any issue while working in on premise Web server. The problem started after migrating to Azure app service.

Comment: You'll have to decide what's easier, upgrading or understanding more about your issue so you can workaround it. You can always put a global lock around all your `Map` calls :)